# Git unstash all files from list

Tags: git, xargs

I created a list by using

```
$ git stash show --name-only | grep -i "Kopie"
```

Output:

```
A - Kopie.txt
B - Kopie.txt
```

How can I unstash all the files from the list?

---

**First Approach:**

```
$ git stash show --name-only | grep -i "Kopie" | xargs git checkout stash@{0} --
```

**Result:**

> ```
> error: pathspec 'A' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> error: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> error: pathspec 'Kopie.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> error: pathspec 'B' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> error: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> error: pathspec 'Kopie.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quoting the filenames when they are passed to `git checkout`, so `A`, `-` & `Kopie.txt` are being treated as different files.

Try adding the `-I {}` option to `xargs`, then put quotes around `{}`:

```
git stash show --name-only | grep -i "Kopie" | xargs -I {} git checkout stash@{0} -- "{}"
```